# How to use tab as delimiter in this cut command?

Tags: cut

```
cut -f2 words.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > counted.txt
```

This command selects the column from the file, count each entry and sort based on frequency, and then output the result to counted.txt, ranked by frequencies, as follows:

```
    1 71321 good
    2 14945 bad
    3 5891 nice
    4 4641 pretty
    5 4494 slow
    6 3671 quick
    ...
```

However, this output delimiter is a white space , and I want a tab as delimiter. I tried the following with --output-delimiter:

```
cut -f2 --output-delimiter='\t' words.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > counted.txt
```

But it reports an error, invalid option.

How to make the output delimiter a tab?

Comment: If you're only selecting a single column, what would setting an output delimiter even do?

Comment: As you can see, this are 2 columns, the first one is freq and the second one is the word.

Comment: What do you mean "*as you can see*"? The only sample data in your question shows 3 columns, not 2. And `cut -f2` selects a single field, not two.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do as follows : 
`cut -d'\t' words.txt -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > counted.txt`

The -d option specifies the delimiter you want to use